# how can I run python file from another file, then have the new file restart the first file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, import, fclose

So far I don't think this is actually possible, but basically what I am trying to do is have one python program call another and run it, like how you would use import.

But then I need to be able to go from the second file back to the beginning of the first.

Doing this with import doesn't work because the first program never closed and will be still running, so running it again will only return to where it left off when it ran the second file.

Comment: sounds like something you should put into a function!

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding a bit more about what you want to do, I would suggest looking into the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#multiprocessing) libraries. These should allow you to create multiple instances of a program or function.

Answer (score 0):

This is vague and I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but you can also explore the [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module for Python. It will allow you to spawn new processes similarly to if you were starting them from the command-line, and your processes will also be able to talk to the child processes via `stdin` and `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import any modules:

```
exec("file.py")
```

Otherwise:

```
import os
os.system('file.py')
```

Or:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('file.py')
```